# How can I get the text of notes in a ppt file via unoconv?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, conversion, convert

I would like to get text of notes for individual slides in PPT to easily accessible format in my linux machine(Ubuntu 12.04).

My goal is to convert PPT slides to image files with meta data, notes as a meta.

I have done till converting PPT to images by using unoconv & convert commands,

initially I converted PPT to PDF by using the following command,

`sudo unoconv -f pdf -o output.pdf input.pptx`

Second, converted these pdf files to png files using following convert command,

`convert output.pdf -density 400 -quality 100 -sharpen 0x1.0 output_%01d.png`

Now, I need to get notes out of it,

I tried converting PPT to xhtml to get notes by using the following unoconv command,

`sudo unoconv -f xhtml -o output.xhtml input.pptx`

But in the above one, can read the notes, but there is no way to parse it by code, it's not in proper structure.

Can anyone help me to get notes out of it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, put the comments in xml and we can try to help you to parse them.

Comment: It's an xhtml, and there is no specific tag associated with notes content, just looks like a normal div, no where mentioned that it's a notes type.

Comment: Try unzipping the ppt and digging around the contents:-). I thin that you may find the notes on the ppt content.

Comment: Wow thank you so much Helio, it helped, able to parse notes after unzipping pptx file.

Comment: You're welcome! Plese, answer yourself with the method used.